# How to send kafka message in webpage

Tags: node.js, vue.js, web, apache-kafka

I have a web page which needs send kafka message to a topic. The web is using vuejs. And I tried using npm "kafka-node" and "kafkajs", they both have errors when establish kafka connection. Maybe they are all server side npm?

Is there any js package that supports webpage to act like kafka producer. I don't want to set up other intermedia servers (like kafka http proxy). I want the webpage directly send messages to topic. Is it workable？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kafka isn't really designed to be publicly accessible in this way, so I would suggest that you use something like the below which allows you to deploy a RESTful interface to your kafka cluster. That way you can just `POST` messages directly to your kafka topic.

https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest

Comment: Thanks, I got it. But I want to avoid other services to receive http then send messages to Kafka. Just wondering if it is workable.